# Multi Variable Limits

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have two questions,

1) One of the questions I had was like this $$\lim_{x,y\to (0,0)}\tan(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{|x|+|y|}\right)$$ and I wasn't too sure on two values I can choose to figure out how to solve this, so what I did was for my first try I set $y=0$, and evaluated it to be 0. Then for the second one I set $x=(\frac{\pi}{4})$ and evaluated it to be $\sin\left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)$. I'm not too sure if I can set values that are not the limits. But my thought process was that we're allowed to set values to equal $0$, and set $x=y$ which is a line, and so it should be ok. Again, not too sure if this is allowed.

2) I'm completely lost on how to solve this question $$\lim_{x,y\to (0,2)}(1+x)^{\large \frac{y}{x}}$$

Comment: If you fix a value, you're not taking the limit. You can take limits along a particular path to get the value along that path. This is a common strategy for proving a limit does not exist. Fixing two different paths and getting two different values. In your example, if you set $y = x$ and take the limit as $x \to 0$, this is a particular path in the plane.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Can we set y equal to be anything? And take it from any plane. Like in how I actually solved it, can I set $y=0$, then solve as $x→0$, and for my second try set $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and solve as $y→0$

Comment: You can test any path you want, but testing paths is not a proof that the limit exists.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, you can sandwich it. Taking the absolute value of the of it means that

$$0\le \left|\tan(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{|x|+|y|}\right)\right| \le |\tan(x)| \to 0$$

As you can see, since $\sin t \le 1$, so you an sandwiching it to $0$.

For the 2nd one consider $$(1+x)^{\frac yx}=e^{\frac{y\log(1+x)}{x}}=e^{\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}}e^y$$

And this is simple.

Comment: Thank you for the steps for the second one, I'll try it right now! As for the first one, using that method I get 0 as well, which is what I got when I set y=0, I need another way that gives me the limit that doesn't equal 0 right

Comment: "I need another way that gives me the limit that doesn't equal 0 right"

You can do that as long as the limit doesn't exist, in this case it exists. Taking any path $(x_n, y_n) \to (0,0)$ will *always* yield $0$

Comment: I get that, and that's what I assumed too, but when I plugged this into wolfram, it said that the limit DNE, doesn't that mean there is some path that won't yield 0? Because if all paths yielded 0 then the limit would be 0 right?

Comment: Usually yes, but in your case, wolframalpha took the complex paths too.

Comment: Rob. Check your very last equation where it says: exp((ylog(x+1))/x) = ....